# Flet: How to implement isolated background blur?

Tags: flet

When I turn on the blur, it takes the color from outside the container and mixes it into the result of the blur. If you make the background of the window transparent, then the blur is not completely applied. How to solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWPY7.png)

```
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "0001"
    page.padding = 0
    page.window_width = 400
    page.window_height = 400
    page.vertical_alignment = 'CENTER'
    page.horizontal_alignment = 'CENTER'
    page.bgcolor = '#ff000000'
    #page.bgcolor = ft.colors.TRANSPARENT
    #page.window_bgcolor = ft.colors.TRANSPARENT


    page.add(
        ft.Container(
            padding=0,
            margin=ft.margin.all(0),
            width=240,
            height=240,
            bgcolor='#ffffffff',
            border_radius=16,
            content=ft.Stack(
                expand=True,
                controls=(
                    [
                        ft.Column(
                            width=240,
                            height=240,
                            expand=True,
                            spacing=0,
                            controls=(
                                [
                                    ft.Container(
                                        width=240,
                                        height=240,
                                        padding=0,
                                        expand=True,
                                        bgcolor='#ffff00ff',
                                        margin=ft.margin.only(left=48, right=48, top=0, bottom=88),
                                        #content=ft.Image(src='0001.jpg', fit='FIT_HEIGHT'),
                                    ),
                                ]
                            ),
                        ),
                        ft.Container(
                            padding=0,
                            height=80,
                            #bgcolor='#8000ff00',
                            blur=16,
                        ),
                    ]
                ),
            )
        )
    )

ft.app(target=main)
```

I tried to change the margins and paddings of containers, but it did not give any result.